# Can I render rails welcome page from my controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I want to show default welcome page by routes.rb,
I can add route like this:

```
  root "rails/welcome#index"
```

Then, I want to render the same template in my controller out of curiosity.
The template is in  `rails/railties/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb`

I thought `render "controller/action" works for my own files,
but it doesn't seem to work for built-in files.

```
  def index
    render "rails/welcome/index"  # This shows error `Missing template rails/welcome/index`.
  end
```

So, Is there a handy way to render built-in template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can render the rails welcome page from your controller by using the `Rails::WelcomeController`

```
class WelcomeController < Rails::WelcomeController

end
```

Don't define the `index` method in `WelcomeController`. Rails will pick the `index` method of `Rails::WelcomeController` and will render the default welcome page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  This does not seem to be handy for general purpose, but might be the only way.